# git@heroku.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: laravel, git, heroku

i want to host my laravel web app in a heroku, i run the following cmd heroku login it is login with success, and then i run cmd next heroku create it runs with success and also touch Procfile it creates a Profile file and i add this web line: vendor / bin / heroku-php-apache2 web / and when i run the cmd git push heroku master i get this error.

```
NAJIB132@NAJIB MINGW32 /d/wamp/www/BTPl (master)
$ git push heroku master
git@heroku.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: What does `git remote -v` show?

Comment: @Chris thx for answer i get $ git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/whispering-dusk-72379.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/whispering-dusk-72379.git (push)

Comment: And is `whispering-dusk-72379` an app you own? Do you see it in your Heroku dashboard?

Comment: @Chris thx its solved

Comment: "its solved"—then please either add your own answer or delete your question.

Comment: @Chris oki thx for information,i just delete file git im my app and i try again